# Copy data from Source sheet to Destination sheet and if the data already exists overwrite the data on Destination Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The main goal is to keep track of the data updated in the Source sheet into the Destination sheet. Every week, the data from the last two weeks gets uploaded onto sheet 1. This week, we loaded weeks 46 and 45 and last week, we loaded weeks 45 and 44. Week 45 should be overwritten in the Destination Sheet with the one we uploaded this week, not the one we loaded last week. Week 46 should also go on the list. My data was transferred from Source to Destination Sheet using the following function.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BQb-_572SbReJWcD8nhfWFj8u4D15jhg7NtrsBT2vz4'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Source'); // ss = source sheet

  var SData = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BQb-_572SbReJWcD8nhfWFj8u4D15jhg7NtrsBT2vz4'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Destination'); // ts = target sheet

  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1,1,SData.length,SData[0].length).setValues(SData);
}
```

I need to change the function so it overwrites week 45 too. I also want only the last 14 weeks data on sheet Destination, so I'll have to delete the weeks before the last 16 weeks. I'd appreciate your help.

Here is the link to the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BQb-_572SbReJWcD8nhfWFj8u4D15jhg7NtrsBT2vz4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: why is the source sheet and target sheet in your code sharing the same ssid?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I need to change the function so it overwrites week 45 too. I also want only the last 14 weeks data on sheet Destination, so I'll have to delete the weeks before the last 16 weeks.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike
Thanks for replying to me. This function copies the whole data from the Source Sheet to the end of the Destination Sheet. In the Destination Sheet, I already have week 45. I want the existing 45 week data to be replaced with the week 45 data from the Source Sheet, as well as week 46 on the end destination sheet. It might be more clear if you open the Google sheet I've attached here

Comment: They are two sheets in one Google Sheet. The Google sheet code is the same @Ping

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, about the values of `week` in "Source" sheet, you want to delete all values of the same `week` values in "Destination" sheet, and append the source values to "Destination" sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly correct!

Comment: @AnnaA if ```They are two sheets in one Google Sheet.```, you should not call openById twice. One of the slowest thing in apps-script is calling these kind of apps-script services repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your reply and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I asked about my understanding, from your reply, I thought that my understanding was correct. But, Unfortunately, from your reply, I understood that my understanding was not correct. I think that this is due to my very poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. And, now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I think that even if I modified my answer, that will not be useful. So, In this case, I would like to delete my answer. I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.
It...

1. looks for the latest 15 weeks of data from 'Source' sheet,
2. clear all contents of 'Destination' sheet,
3. throw the data found in step-1 into the empty 'Destination' sheet.

Note: you can change the value of the variable 'limit' to set how many weeks of data do you want to bring into your 'Destination' sheet.

If you want a target sheet to keep updated with latest data of a set period, instead of checking the whole target sheet for old data to be deleted, and try to insert new data that doesn't exists to the right place,

just delete everthing on it and re-insert the data which should stay, is always the faster, easier, and more reliable way to go.

```js
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  const limit = 15;
  const ssid = '1BQb-_572SbReJWcD8nhfWFj8u4D15jhg7NtrsBT2vz4';
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  const ss = sss.getSheetByName('Source');
  const ts = sss.getSheetByName('Destination');
  const sValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  const dates = sValues
    .map(([year,week,...rest]) => [year,week].join(''))
    .filter((n,i,s) => !isNaN(n) && i === s.indexOf(n))
    .reverse()
    .filter((v,i) => i<limit)
    .map(v => [v.slice(0,4),v.slice(4)]);
  
  const results = sValues.filter(([year,week,...rest],i) => {
    return dates.some(([dYear,dWeek]) => year == dYear && week == dWeek) || i === 0;
  });

  ts.clearContents();
  ts.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

BUT!

If you source sheet do not always contains data of all time, that wouldn't work.

In that case, try this second attempt:

1. This code compares the 'year' and 'week' of 'Source' and 'Destination' sheet,
2. get source data that has year & week lager than those in 'Destination' sheet,
3. re-create values of 'Destination' sheet with the added new entries,
4. remove the old-values which exceeded the set 'limit' week count,
5. clear the target sheet,
6. setValues back to target sheet.

```js
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  const limit = 15;
  const getDates = (values) => {
    return values
      .map(([year,week,...rest]) => [year,week].join(''))
      .filter((n,i,s) => !isNaN(n) && i === s.indexOf(n))
      .reverse()
  }
  const ssid = '1BQb-_572SbReJWcD8nhfWFj8u4D15jhg7NtrsBT2vz4';
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  const ss = sss.getSheetByName('Source');
  const ts = sss.getSheetByName('Destination');
  const sValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tValues = ts.getDataRange().getValues(); // < typo, was ss.getDataRange(), it should be ts.getDataRange() instead.
  const sDates = getDates(sValues);
  const tDates = getDates(tValues);
  const nDates = sDates.filter(n => n > Math.max(...tDates));
  const aDates = tDates.concat(nDates).filter((val,i) => i<limit);
  const results = [];
  for (const [year,week,...rest] of sValues) {
    if (nDates.includes([year,week].join(''))) tValues.push([year,week,...rest]);
  }
  for (const [i,[year,week,...rest]] of tValues.entries()) {
    if (i === 0 || aDates.includes([year,week].join(''))) results.push([year,week,...rest]);
  }

  ts.clearContents();
  ts.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

maybe sort the date values before comparing can slove the problem, also I have rearranged some of the variables for easier access and update:

```js
function CopyDataToNewFile2() {
  const limit = 15; // limit of week counts to be returned
  const ssid = '1BQb-_572SbReJWcD8nhfWFj8u4D15jhg7NtrsBT2vz4'; // id of the spreadsheet
  const source = 'Source' // Source sheet name;
  const destination = 'Destination' // Destination sheet name;

  const getDates = (values) => {
    return values
      .map(([year,week,...rest]) => [year,week].join(''))
      .filter((n,i,s) => !isNaN(n) && i === s.indexOf(n))
  }
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  const ss = sss.getSheetByName(source);
  const ts = sss.getSheetByName(destination);
  const sValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tValues = ts.getDataRange().getValues(); // < typo, was ss.getDataRange(), it should be ts.getDataRange() instead.
  const sDates = getDates(sValues);
  const tDates = getDates(tValues);
  const nDates = sDates.filter(n => n > Math.max(...tDates));
  const aDates = tDates.concat(nDates).sort((a,b) => b - a).filter((val,i) => i<limit);
  const results = [];
  for (const [year,week,...rest] of sValues) {
    if (nDates.includes([year,week].join(''))) tValues.push([year,week,...rest]);
  }
  for (const [i,[year,week,...rest]] of tValues.entries()) {
    if (i === 0 || aDates.includes([year,week].join(''))) results.push([year,week,...rest]);
  }

  ts.clearContents();
  ts.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

Instead of just copy the new entries form source sheet, this code will also replace the values in target sheet if the date of given data appears in source sheet:

```js
function CopyDataToNewSheet() {
  const limit = 17; // limit of week counts to be returned
  const ssid = '1Yf6RItkwa6T1pZEt-RFZRdapdy2NfoFgKUCMxqPbSD4'; // id of the spreadsheet
  const source = 'Source' // Source sheet name;
  const destination = 'Destination' // Destination sheet name;
  const getDates = (values) => {
    return values
      .map(([year,week,...rest]) => [year,week].join(''))
      .filter((n,i,s) => !isNaN(n) && i === s.indexOf(n))
    
  }

  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid); //open the spread sheet
  const ss = sss.getSheetByName(source);
  const ts = sss.getSheetByName(destination);
  const sValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tValues = ts.getDataRange().getValues();
  const sDates = getDates(sValues);
  const tDates = getDates(tValues).sort((a,b) => b - a);
  const oDates = tDates.filter(d => !sDates.includes(d)).filter((v,i) => i<(limit-sDates.length));
  tValues.shift();
  for (const [i,[year,week,...rest]] of tValues.entries()) {
    if (!!i && oDates.includes([year,week].join(''))) sValues.push([year,week,...rest]);
  }
  const results = sValues.sort((a,b) => [b[0],b[1]].join('') - [a[0],a[1]].join(''));

  ts.clearContents();
  ts.getRange(1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works! Just a question. How do I automate this? Right now, I have to run it manually in Apps Script. Is there a way I can have the data sent to the destination every time the source data changes? That means the function runs as soon as the source sheet data changes.

Comment: you can achieve automation by installable trigger.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Here is the logic I am thinking about. Do you have a better logic? 

1) Deletes the oldest week from the destination tab.
2) Also in the destination tab, looks if there are any rows which match the same weeks as the source tab, and remove them.
3) Places all the source info into the destination tab.

Comment: Added a new piece of code to achive your request.