# Copy all data from one sheet to another with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this situation:

- a form response destination tab called 'GIORNALIERA', in spreadsheet file 1, with the original data, that i get from submissions on Google Forms. This data will change, with new rows added through new form response submissions every day. From time to time, rows are also manually deleted in this tab.

| Timestamp | EMPLOYEE IN SERVICE | DATE | ROUTE | START TIME | END TIME | HOURS/MINUTES OF PAUSE | KM TRAVELED | PETROL | EXPENSES | MEAL EXPENSES | OVERNIGHT EXPENSES | MISCELLANEOUS EXPENSES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 14:15:00 | Luke Skywalker | 07/10/2022 | Tatooine | 11.00.00 | 13.00.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 8 KM | € 1,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 |
| 2023-01-02 18:25:00 | John Doe | 28/09/2021 | Abafar | 7.20.00 | 11.30.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 5 KM | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 |
| … | Anakin Skywalker | 04/03/2022 | Tatooine | 22.55.00 | 1.05.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 0 KM | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 |
| … | John Doe | 23/08/2022 | Tatooine | 8.15.00 | 19.10.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 90 KM | € 18,00 | € 27,50 | € 0,00 | € 149,00 |
| … | Anakin Skywalker | 13/10/2022 | Abafar | 17.00.00 | 19.30.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 20 KM | € 2,50 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 |
| … | Luke Skywalker | 05/09/2022 | Abafar | 20.45.00 | 2.35.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 94 KM | € 18,80 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 32,00 |

- a tab called 'Foglio13' in spreadsheet file 2, in which i need to append the data from the original sheet, and keep that data even if it gets deleted from the source
- another tab in spreadsheet file 2, in which i need to append all the rows if the first column in the source contains a specific name, and as above, keeps that data even if it gets deleted from the source. The output, for example, for Luke Skywalker would be this:

| Timestamp | EMPLOYEE IN SERVICE | DATE | ROUTE | START TIME | END TIME | HOURS/MINUTES OF PAUSE | KM TRAVELED | PETROL | EXPENSES | MEAL EXPENSES | OVERNIGHT EXPENSES | MISCELLANEOUS EXPENSES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 14:15:00 | Luke Skywalker | 07/10/2022 | Tatooine | 11.00.00 | 13.00.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 8 KM | € 1,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 |
| … | Luke Skywalker | 05/09/2022 | Abafar | 20.45.00 | 2.35.00 | 0.00.00 | 0 | 94 KM | € 18,80 | € 0,00 | € 0,00 | € 32,00 |

This is the current code that i'm using, but it has one issue. If i run the function again it appends all the data, but i want to append only new data that hasn't been appended before

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("PANORAMICA");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Foglio13");

  var rows = copySheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets the rows with data

  rows.map(row => pasteSheet.appendRow(row)); // Appends the rows to the second sheet
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this, is just copy the sheet with the ```.copyTo()``` method.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)

Comment: This function do similar things, you can make a slight change to fit it into your case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541059/copy-data-from-source-sheet-to-destination-sheet-and-if-the-data-already-exists/74541554#74541554

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear which rows should get copied, and whether they should simply be appended to the target sheet or something else. Please edit the question to specify your exact requirements. Use [tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) to show sample data and your desired results.

Comment: edited OP following advices

Comment: How would you identify that a particular row is "new"? Are existing rows ever edited? If they are, and the first row is edited so that the Start Time is 11:15, is the whole row considered "new" and thus appended to the second tab?

Comment: existing rows are never edited. To identify a particular row, since i get the original data from Google Forms, i have the date and time when the form it's compiled.

Comment: Those details are missing from the question. Please edit the question to specify that the 'PANORAMICA' tab is a form responses destination sheet, and that you simply want to copy responses as they get submitted. Also edit the tables to show the Timestamp column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy form responses from the form responses tab to another tab as they are submitted, use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

```js
/**
* Installable trigger that runs each time a form response is submitted.
*
* Create an installable "on form submit" trigger to run this function:
* https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually
*
* @param {Object} e The "on form submit" event object.
*/
function appendDataOnFormSubmit(e) {
  'use strict';
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the appendDataOnFormSubmit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when a form response is submitted.'
    );
  }
  let archiveSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('..put target spreadsheet ID here...');
  let archiveSheet = archiveSs.getSheetByName('Foglio13');
  if (!archiveSheet) {
    archiveSheet = archiveSs.insertSheet(appendRowsToArchiveSheetSettings.targetSheet);
    const formResponsesSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('GIORNALIERA');
    const headers = formResponsesSheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues().flat();
    archiveSheet.appendRow(headers);
  }
  const newRowData = e.range.getValues().flat();
  archiveSheet.appendRow(newRowData);
}
```

To create additional tabs for each employee that show only "their" subset of the archived data, use `=query()` formulas, like this:

```
=query(Foglio13!A1:Z, "where B = 'Luke Skywalker' ", 1)
```

Alternatively, use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to show one employee at a time directly in the archive sheet.

Comment: looks like it's not workign, maybe because the file where "GIORNALIERA" is, is different from the where "Foglio13" is

Comment: I'm getting "ReferenceError: ss is not defined"

Comment: It is unclear what 'GIORNALIERA' is. To refer to a tab in another spreadsheet file, use `SpreadsheetApp.openById('...').getSheetByName('...')`. Replace `ss` with `e.source`. Please add all relevant detail in the question.

Comment: 'GIORNALIERA' is a tab on Sheet1, while 'Foglio13' is a tab on a different sheet, so the sheets are different.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy all data to another sheet, instead of copying the data, you can just copy the sheet itself.

The following functions will copy the source sheet to the target spreadsheet, and rename that sheet as your target sheet name, if a sheet with shuch name already exists, it will be deleted.

```js
// if the source sheet and the target sheet is in the different spreadsheet:
function copySheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source SpreadSheet ID");
  const source = ss.getSheetByName("Source Sheet Name");
  const target = ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet Name");
  if(!!target) ss.deleteSheet(target);
  source.copyTo(ss).setName("Target Sheet Name");
}

// if the source sheet and the target sheet is in the same spreadsheet:
function importSheet() {
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source SpreadSheet ID");
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Target SpreadSheet ID");
  const source = sss.getSheetByName("Source Sheet Name");
  const target = tss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet Name");
  if(!!target) tss.deleteSheet(target);
  source.copyTo(tss).setName("Target Sheet Name");
}
```

Comment: tried your first solution but isn't working as i expected, because the data in the source sheet changes every day and i need to keep a copy, even if it get deleted in the source sheet

Comment: what are you trying to do? the sample code you have in your question clear everything of the target sheet before copying the data from source sheet, there should have little to no different from "delete everything on target sheet than copy data form source sheet"; and "delete the target sheet, than copy the source sheet and name it as target sheet".

Comment: if you are not willing to delete everything on the target sheet, your sample code would be totally wrong, in that case, you should make it clear what your exepected result is.

Comment: In the source sheet, new data will be added every day. With your approach, if i delete the row #1 in the source sheet, it will be also deleted in the target sheet. I need to copy the data from the source like once or twice a day, and keep in the target even if it gets deleted in the source

Comment: you should mention these in your question lol

Comment: i just edited OP